# ffmpeg - extract subtitles (which are unencrypted) when video is encrypted

Tags: ffmpeg

I have a .wtv file, recorded from Windows Media Center, that I'd like to extract the subtitles from. The video is encrypted, but the subtitles are not (something I've been able to verify by using [CCExtractor](http://ccextractor.sourceforge.net) with it). FFMpeg lists the video as such:

```
Duration: 00:07:01.72, start: 2.214551, bitrate: 9154 kb/s
Stream #0:0[0xcc](eng): Audio: ac3, 48000 Hz, 5.1(side), fltp, 384 kb/s
Stream #0:1[0xcd]: Video: mpeg2video (Main), yuv420p(tv), 1920x1080 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], Closed Captions, max. 25000 kb/s, 29.97 fps, 29.97 tbr, 10000k tbn, 59.94 tbc
Stream #0:2[0xce]: Subtitle: eia_608
```

When I try to run

```
ffmpeg -i myvideofile.wtv -an -vn -map 0:2 -c:s:0 srt test.srt
```

I see a lot of the following errors:

```
[wtv @ 0x7fef79806e00] encrypted stream detected (st:1), decoding will likely fail
Last message repeated 8 times
[Closed caption Decoder @ 0x7fef7982cc00] Data Ignored since exceeding screen width
```

and eventually:

```
Output file is empty, nothing was encoded (check -ss / -t / -frames parameters if used)
```

I don't mind it being able to decode the video stream, but is that causing the closed caption error? If it can't decode the video it doesn't know the screen width, perhaps? Is it possible to set the closed caption decoder to ignore such errors and output anyway (it's just in text format after all)?

Comment: You need to: 1) Show the complete console output from your command. You may trim the repeating messages. 2) Provide a sample input file if possible.

Comment: I can't provide the sample file as it is copyrighted content (hence the encryption). In any case, I am now using CCExtractor without invoking ffmpeg at all, so unfortunately I am no longer pursuing an answer to this question.